# Normalizing signed values results in values outside 0 and 1

Tags: c#

I am trying to create some kind of heatmap to visualize data I get from a sensor. So far this works but it looked odd. So I figured out that my code which normalizes the values (ranging from at least -100 to 100) must be invalid.

I often got exceptions because the factor (the normalized value) I use to calculate the color (byte) was negative or greater than 1.

So I modified my code and basically shifted min, max and the value by `Math.Abs(min)` to ensure that my values are positive. The negative issue is fixed but I sometimes end up with values like *1.02xxxx* which must not happen. **EDIT:** Still getting negative values in some cases...

This is my code so far:

```
double min = data.Min();
double max = data.Max();
double avg = data.Average();
double v = max - min;

byte a, b, g, r;

// Set minimum and maximum
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    Minimum = min;
    Maximum = max;
    Average = avg;
});

double shift = 0;
if (min < 0) // If minimum is negative, shift it to 0 and everything else positively by Abs(min)
{
    max += shift = Math.Abs(min);
    min += shift;
}

int skipFactor = (int)(1 / _pointResolution);
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += skipFactor)
{
    // If min == 0 then shift data
    double value = Math.Abs(min) < 0.0001d ? (data[i] + shift) / max : (data[i] - min) / v;
...
}
```

How can I fix this without adding rounding or "edge-cases"? I assume the `Math.Abs()` combined with adding operations results in slightly off values... But there must be a solution to that, right?

Comment: Why don't use rounding?

Comment: Because I am working on a representation of optically measured values. Rounding would kinda destroy the whole idea of that. I think I already found the reason for this. Can't completely confirm it yet, but my guess is this was because I haven't cloned the arrays I normalize while another thread is writing on them. The values were obviously changed during calculation and thus the boundaries weren't right anymore.